# При открытии выборки выдаётся ошибка: KeyError: "labels ['Y1'] not contained in axis"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии выборки выдает ошибку, что не так я сделала с выборкой?

Ссылка на выборку
https://ru.files.fm/u/zra6xdbg#_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема вызвана пробелом перед `Y1` в CSV файле.

В результате имя первого столбца `' Y1'`, вместо ожидаемого `'Y1'`:

```
In [25]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\data.csv', sep=';')

In [26]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[26]: [' Y1', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8']
# NOTE: -> ^
```

воспользуйтесь параметром `skipinitialspace=True`:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\data.csv', sep=';', skipinitialspace=True)

In [28]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[28]: ['Y1', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8']
```

Comment: работает, спасибо)

Comment: user280357 отметь ответ как правильный.

Comment: @user280357, помогу Александру :) [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)